# How is it possible to prevent retention or re-use of data by sent to cognitive services?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

In the Azure [speech-to-text FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/faq-stt) it states: "you have a choice when you create a deployment to switch off tracing. At that point, no audio or transcriptions will be logged".

I have looked for that option when deploying the speech API but without success. How exactly do you switch off tracing?

By doing that, is it the case that no audio or transcript is retained or further processed or sent anywhere by Azure as a result of calling the speech API whether as part of the logging referred to in the FAQ or for any other purpose or by any other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, no audio is logged. If you turn on tracing the audio is stored in the region you are calling. The audio is only retrievable by the customer. Others does not have access to the audio and thus does not use it.This is inline with Azure OST.

For all compliance related details. Please, go through [compliance and privacy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/cognitive-services-compliance-and-privacy/) page for more information about how you can manage your data.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ram. Having gone through the compliance and privacy page it is my understanding that use of cognitive services, including speech-to-text are covered by the [Microsoft Online Services Terms](https://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/Downloader.aspx?DocumentId=15154).

As such, "Customer Data will be used or otherwise processed only to provide Customer the Online Services including purposes compatible with providing those services. Microsoft will not use or otherwise process Customer Data or derive information from it for any advertising or similar commercial purposes.".

Comment: So I think the full answer to my question is that:
1. No audio is retained unless tracing is actively chosen to be switched on
2. The transcript is stored until I delete it
3. Neither the audio nor the transcript are processed or stored other than for the purpose of providing the transcript.